# Difference between Geometry and Geometry collections

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Please can anyone explain the difference between
`$table->geometry('positions');` and `$table->geometryCollection('positions');` in laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your database is MySQL. Please add it as a tag to your post then.

According to the manual:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-type-overview.html

> Some spatial data types hold single geometry values:
>
> GEOMETRY
>
> GEOMETRY can store geometry values of any type. The other single-value types (POINT, LINESTRING, and POLYGON) restrict their values to a particular geometry type.

and

> The other spatial data types hold collections of values:
>
> GEOMETRYCOLLECTION
>
> GEOMETRYCOLLECTION can store a collection of objects of any type. The other collection types (MULTIPOINT, MULTILINESTRING, and MULTIPOLYGON) restrict collection members to those having a particular geometry type.

The difference is that the last one can hold multiple entities (coordinates/points) in a single column. This is useful if you want to save a square shape for instance, which needs 4 points.

A practical example for the first one would be a location (which is a single set of coordinates (lat+lng)).

I sadly cant give you much information on how to use them within Laravel. However in raw SQL, it basically looks like this:

```sql
-- Add data to a GEOMETRY column
SET @g = 'POINT(1 1)';
INSERT INTO geo VALUES (ST_GeomFromText(@g));
```

```sql
-- Add data to a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION column
SET @g = 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(1 1),LINESTRING(0 0,1 1,2 2,3 3,4 4))';
INSERT INTO geocol VALUES (ST_GeomFromText(@g));
```